# Azure B2C returns FORBIDDEN (403) on health checks via Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, azure, http, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Since last Monday (6th March 2023) the health endpoint of all our Azure B2Cs (Dev, Staging & Prod) returns in about 20% of all requests a 403 (`FORBIDDEN`) HTTP status with the following message: `Cannot get company information for the tenant, Please check Cloud Id or retry for another tenant.` This leads to constant health alerts in our systems.

[Availibilty (last 24h) of our productive environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YR9BG.png)

For all our requests to the Azure B2Cs we use the [.NET Microsoft Graph SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) with client secret credentials. I've validated all secrets/IDs and the bearer token in the HTTP calls and they are all correct. Curiously, some HTTP calls with the same bearer token lead to a 200 (`OK`) HTTP status, some to a 403 (`FORBIDDEN`) HTTP status.

Does anyone has the same problem? It seems to me that Azure has changed something internally, otherwise I can't explain why the error occurs only in some cases. Furthermore this issue doesn't affect other endpoints via Microsoft Graph (see table on the bottom).

### Initialization and usage of the Microsoft Graph Client

The `graphClient` is registered in the `DI` container in our Azure App Service as singleton.

```cs
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = appSettings.B2C_GRAPH_TENANT_ID;
var clientId = appSettings.B2C_GRAPH_CLIENT_ID;
var clientSecret = appSettings.B2C_GRAPH_CLIENT_SECRET;
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud };
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
...
```

The health endpoint is called periodically by our health check:

```
public async Task<bool> IsHealthy(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    try
    {
        var serviceHealths = await _graphClient.Admin.ServiceAnnouncement.HealthOverviews
            .Request()
            .GetAsync(cancellationToken);

        return serviceHealths.Single(h => h.Id == _serviceHealthId)
                .Status is ServiceHealthStatus.ServiceOperational;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Client permissions in Azure B2C

[Client permissions in Azure B2C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frozo.png)

### HTTP

Here is a logging of a HTTP call and the returned 403 response on our staging environment:

**HTTP request**

```
RequestUri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/healthOverviews', Version: 2.0, Content: <null>, Headers:
{
   SdkVersion: Graph-dotnet-2.0.12
   FeatureFlag: 00000047
   Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
   Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]
   Accept-Encoding: gzip
}
```

**HTTP reply**

```
StatusCode: 403, ReasonPhrase: 'Forbidden', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler+GZipDecompressedContent, Headers:
{
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Vary: Accept-Encoding
   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
   request-id: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
   client-request-id: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
   x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"XXXXXXXXXXXXX"}}
   X-Instance: westeurope/_readvm_3
   X-TimeTaken: 130
   Date: Wed, 08 Mar 2023 10:30:18 GMT
   Content-Type: application/json
   Content: {"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"{\"code\":\"forbidden\",\"message\":\"{\\u0022error\\u0022:\\u0022Cannot get company information for the tenant, Please check Cloud Id or retry for another tenant. ActivityId: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX. Learn more: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/service-communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta\\\\u0026preserve-view=true.\\u0022}\"}","innerError":{"date":"2023-03-08T10:30:18","request-id":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX","client-request-id":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"}}}
}
```

#### Returned HTTP status codes for each endpoint

| HTTP status | Endpoint | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | GET /v.1.0/users | 15,070 |
| 200 | GET /v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/healthOverviews | 2.676 |
| 204 | DELETE /v.1.0/users | 10 |
| 204 | PATCH /v.1.0/users | 7 |
| 403 | GET /v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/healthOverviews | 776 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the scenario.

Have run the request **Get**

***`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/healthOverviews`***

With permissions given to the user :

[image]

With access token provided which has all the permissions above which is retrieved from following endpoint:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:b6xxxxc4
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
client_secret:FXIxxxxcjA
grant_type:client_credentials
redirect_url:https://jwt.ms
```

With the token received:

[image]

When run the same query with other user, it gave me the 403 forbidden error.

**Forbidden - 403**

[image]

When I checked ,the issue was the user signed in with different tenant other than where the permissions are actually granted to the user.

So , the users , must make sure to sign in to their correct tenant .
They must make sure that they are **granted admin consent** to all the permissions required to query.

**Reference:** [List healthOverviews - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceannouncement-list-healthoverviews?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks for your effort - I really appreciate it. Since Wednesday, the problem has resolved itself and I don't get any 403 responses anymore. :/ However, I've checked the app registration permissions and they seemed correct to me. All permissions are granted by my global administrator account.